# meson and -include file search path invocation

Tags: gcc, args, ninja, meson-build

Hi I need do pass to gcc an header file with the following path invocation

```
-I<folder> -include <header>
e.g.
-I/usr/include/dpdk -include rte_config.h
```

in meson build i decide to pass it as c_args

but than in the ninja build I found

> '-I/usr/include/dpdk$ -include$ rte_config.h'

with a need of a post processing to clean the ninja file,

Is possible to avoid this problem?

in meson.build I have

```py
if (get_option('avx_opt') == 'avx512')
    build_args_avx = [
      '-DNEWLDPC=1',
      '-mavx512f',
      '-mavx512cd',
      '-mavx512vl',
      '-mavx512bw',
      '-mavx512dq',
    ]
else
    build_args_avx = [
      '-DNEWLDPC=0',
    ]
endif

if host_machine.system() == 'qnx7'
    build_args_machine = [
        '-march=broadwell',
    ]
else
    build_args_machine = [
        '-I/usr/include/dpdk -include rte_config.h',
        '-march=broadwell',
    ]
endif

build_args = [
  '-imacros' + sourceRoot + '/src/nr5g-phy/common/inc/phyConfig.h',
  '-imacros' + sourceRoot + '/project/infoBuild.h',
  '-mfpmath=387',
  '-ffast-math',
  build_args_machine,
  build_args_avx,
  '-g',
  '-Wall',
  '-Werror',
  '-O3',
  '-std=gnu11',
  '-fms-extensions',
]

...  

project_source_files,
  dependencies:   [...],
  install : false,
  c_args : build_args,
  link_args : '-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined',
  include_directories : public_headers,
  build_rpath : '/lsu/sdr/lib'
)


'''
```

Comment: are you trying to build application with DPDK Library using meson?  If yes, you have an option to invoke pkg-config directly. Let me know

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese
the appliaction I'm porting to the new build sisyem meson does not link directly the dpdk library, but need some header file of dpdk.

Comment: I means that the application I'm building with meson link an external library that include dpdk shared lib, so the main application does not link directly the dpdk lib but need only some dpdk include.

but the problem of this issue is not dpdk itself is how meson handle path invocation like

-I<folder> -include <myheader.h>

Comment: that is why I requested twice to setup a 15 min debug to  help resolve the issue. Since your application is using a library (which includes the dpdk library). It is in the linking phase where you need to ensure the DPDK librarioes are availble. Not as a compiler flag.

Comment: I had luck in using libraries built with DPDK into other meson and cmake projects. Based on the latest comments `Please update your question with the real intent as mentioned above comment and share the meson code snippet`

Comment: as you have mentioned in the comment you are using a library which is build with DPDK libraries, why is that you are trying `build_args_machine = ['-I/usr/include/dpdk -include rte_config.h',  '-march=broadwell',` ? Will you be able to come for a debug?

Comment: waiting for your update on live debug availability

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese
the problem is in the public header file of the lib I include in my application, I have asked to the team involved to hide externally any include of the dpdk header files.